# Tokens start with double quotes followed by some tokens and end with double quotes, into one token

Tags: java, eclipse, windows

I am parsing around 10 number of CSV files

[image]

and doing tokenization. So the fourth token 'PageTitle' sometimes start with double quotes ("). For that, I am taking special  care like this

```
String page = st.nextToken();
if(page.startsWith("\""))
{
        String s;
        while(!(s=st.nextToken()).endsWith("\""))
        {
        System.out.println(page);
        page += (","+s);
        System.out.println(page);

    }
    page += (","+s);
    page = page.substring(0, page.length());
}
```

I don't know where I am doing mistake but I want to read tokens, which start with double quotes followed by some tokens and end with double quotes, into one token like this

"List of lesbian, gay, bisexual or transgender-related films of 2012"

But I am getting only "List of lesbian, gay

Comment: Use a CSV parsing library.

Comment: In a "..." CSV field also line breaks may occur, maybe not CR-LF but LF. Check that there is a next field "bisexual".  Check the data in a programmers editor (Notepad++ or such).

Comment: By the way String concatenation, using +, += is really slow; try a StringBuilder when all works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rolling out your own parser , you can use a library like OpenCSV. You will need to do the following

a) Add dependency , if you are using maven

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

To illustrate i have used the following sample data , saved as data.csv on WD

```
one , two , three
four,five,"read , these , numerals"
```

c) Sample code

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("data.csv"));
    String [] nextLine;
    while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
        System.out.println("Column 1 :"+nextLine[0]);
        System.out.println("Column 2 :"+nextLine[1]);
        System.out.println("Column 3 :"+ nextLine[2]);
    }

}
```

prints :

```
Column 1 :one 
Column 2 : two 
Column 3 : three
Column 1 :four
Column 2 :five
Column 3 :read , these , numerals
```